# TFS2018 why is shelveset name empty?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

When queue-ing a build manually using TFS2018 the shelveset name is not showing the source branch name in all cases. Sometimes it is filled out sometimes not. Since I am picking up build variables for the source branch
 $(Build.SourceBranch)
$(Build.SourceBranchName)

They will be empty if the Shelveset name is empty.

[image]

Is it possible to set the shelveset name default as the sourcebranch using the API when creating the build definition?

Is there another build variable that I can use to get the source path for the currently built solution?

UPDATE So I am trying to update the source branches using the build api. However when called I get a

{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-TFS-ProcessId: 
  ActivityId: 
  X-TFS-Session: 
  X-VSS-E2EID: 
  X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
  X-VSS-UserData: :user
  Persistent-Auth: true
  Lfs-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2018 14:37:16 GMT
  P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 93
  Allow: GET
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}

for the following code....

```
internal void UpdateSourceBranches(List<BuildDefinition> defs)
        {
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tfsUser, tfsPass) })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tfsServer);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    foreach (var def in defs)
                    {
                        var buildId = def.Id;
                        var sourceBranch = $"$/{def.Repository.Name}/{def.Project.Name}";
                        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "BuildConfiguration", "release" },
                        { "BuildPlatform", "x86|x64|ARM" },
                        { "system.debug", "true" }
                    };

                        var jsonParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

                        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", buildId.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sourceBranch", sourceBranch),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parameters", jsonParams)
                        });

                        var response = client.PostAsync($"DefaultCollection/{def.Repository.Name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.0-preview.1", content);
                        var s = response.Result;
                    }                  
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT Thanks for your answer. It seems the problem I had was related to the way I was creating the build definition. I will have a better look at it at a later time.

Comment: You should use `Queue a build` api instead of `create a build definition` api for this part.

Comment: If you want to see shelveset name in the queue dialogue, you could map the exact source branch in `Get sources` of your build definition.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Queue a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) api to set SourceBranch, for example:

```
POST http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "definition": {
    "id": 47
  },
  "sourceBranch":"$/CeceScrum/TestCaseProject",
  "parameters":"{\"BuildConfiguration\":\"release\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"any cpu\",\"system.debug\":\"false\"}"
}
```

If you want to choose a shelveset to build, then the api looks like below:

```
POST http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0

    Content-Type: application/json

    {
      "definition": {
        "id": 47
      },
      "sourceBranch":"ceceShelveset;domain\\username",
      "parameters":"{\"BuildConfiguration\":\"release\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"any cpu\",\"system.debug\":\"false\"}"
    }
```

Comment: Hi @CeceDong actually I get a Method Not Allowed after I set the correct api version...

Comment: You should use `api-version=2.0`.